# Checkstyle for java extension in vscode

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I am writing a single java file for a simple program and I am trying to format it to align with Google's style guide for java. I have downloaded checkstyle for java and Language support for java by Red Hat. In the documentation for the checkstyle for java it says you can:

> You can also trigger the command Checkstyle: Set Checkstyle Configuration File to choose the configuration file in the File Explorer. The extension will automatically detect and list the Checkstyle configuration files in your workspace. Besides that, you will also see the two built-in configurations:
>
> Google's Check
>
> Sun's Check

I am wondering if anybody knows exactly how to use the checkstyle for java in vscode and run the command to configure it for google's check and to run it to format it for google's check

Link to repo: https://github.com/jdneo/vscode-checkstyle

Answer (score 0):

Never mind I figured it out. It turns out you just right click to get the command palette

Answer (score 0):

Use `ctrl+shift+P` to open the command palette and then look for - Checkstyle: Set Checkstyle Configuration.

As mentioned in the plugin you can use the default built in Checkstyles.

1. Google's check
2. Sun's check

Or you can specify the

1. URL
2. File location
   to use the checkstyle.